# Using getElementById from external JavaScript to an asp Literal variable

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I'm trying to read a variable named `ID="_errors"` into my javascript using `getElementById`, but something about my implementation causes my JS file to be ignored.

This is the HTML:

```
...
    <asp:TextBox ID="_password" CssClass="login" runat="server" TextMode="Password" />
    <label class="mylabel" for="<%=_errors.ClientID%>"></label>
    <table id="table1">      
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 100px;"></td>        
            <td><span class="response1" runat="server"><asp:Literal ID="_errors" runat="server" /></span></td>                           
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 280px;"></td>
            <td><asp:Button ID="_login" CssClass="mybutton" runat="server" Text="Login" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
...
```

This is how I reference `_errors` in my .js file:

```
var PassWord            = document.getElementById('_login__password').value;
var Errors              = document.getElementById('_login__errors').value;
```

I reference my `PassWord` value here, because it works just fine. By viewing my page source I use the ClientID to know what the ID for `_errors` is.I did the same for `PassWord`. The thing that worries me (and the likely source of the error) is that the portion `<asp:Literal ID="_errors" runat="server" />` does not show up in the page source at all. Any clue as to what might be the problem here?

Comment: You are not seeing the Literal control rendered on the page because without its Text property set, it will not render anything - including a wrapping tag the way that a Label control does.

Answer (score 1):

When you put a literal control in your page, it simply renders the content without enclosing it into any html element

For example:

```
<Asp:literal runat="Server" Text="Hello" />
```

Will render as:

```
 Hello
```

Therefore, the call to `document.getElementById` fails because there's no element with that id...

If you want the literal control to render as span with an id, then set the Text property like this:

```
<asp:literal runat="server" Text="<span id='_errors'>Hello</span>" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't access the literal by it's ID, as already stated.

You could simply set the ID on the surrounding `<span>` and make that element "run at server":

```
...
    <asp:TextBox ID="_password" CssClass="login" runat="server" TextMode="Password" />
    <label class="mylabel" for="<%=_errors.ClientID%>"></label>
    <table id="table1">      
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 100px">&nbsp;</td>        
            <td><span ID="_errors" class="response1" runat="server" /></td>                           
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 100px">&nbsp;</td>
            <td><asp:Button ID="_login" CssClass="mybutton" runat="server" Text="Login" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
...
```

Notes:

- I also added `&nbsp;` to your otherwise empty `td`-elements, to prevent displaying problems
- You can't set different sizes on cells within the same column